# SQL ORDER BY clause ERROR in the ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I want to use ROW_NUMBER() function and get first and latest values.
I write bellow query. But I got an error.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

---

help me to solve the issue. Below the sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT OPP_ID,PRJ_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OPP_ID ORDER BY MAX(CREATION_DATE) DESC) AS RN
    FROM OPPOR
    GROUP BY OPP_ID,PRJ_ID
    ORDER BY MAX(CREATION_DATE) DESC) OP
WHERE OP.RN = 1
```

Comment: you can't use ORDER BY inside a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row_number` function can do it's own aggregation and ordering, so no need to use `group by` or `order by` in your subquery (`order by` won't work in subqueries as you've seen).  It is a little unclear if you want to `partition by` opp_id or opp_id and prj_id though.  But this should be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT OPP_ID,PRJ_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OPP_ID ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC) AS RN
    FROM OPPOR
    ) OP
WHERE OP.RN = 1
```